# Recursive fluent builder

Tags: java, generics, fluent-interface

**Problem statement**

I have entities whose relations form a graph. As an example, let's imagine `User`s and `Group`s. Each user has a `Set` of groups s*he belongs to; each `Group` has a `Set` of `User`s, representing its members. When constructing objects of those types, there is no clear hierachy. One could start by constructing a `Group` and add `User`s to the group, as well as start with constructing an `User` and add `Group`s to that user.

To ease construction, I want to have a fluent API for constructing those objects. Looking online, the most advanced solutions I have found assume a hieracical (i.e. tree-like) relation model, e.g.:

- An `Order` has `OrderItem`s
- `OrderItems` have an `OrderDescription`
- ....

Implementing this kind of fluent builder is easy enough, since an `OrderItemBuilder` always needs some kind of callback to an `Order`, and an Order always needs to have a `build()` method.

With the `User`-`Group`-example, the separation is not as clear. When starting construction a `User`-objects, a `build()`-method must be present. Starting a (recursive) `Group`-construction, the builder must not provide `build()`, but `and()` (or some other callback-method) instead. Here is an example usage:

```
Group root = groupBuilder // may be injected through some means
    .withName("root")
    .withUser()
        .name("John Doe")
        .email("john@doe.com")
        // must not compile:
        // .build()
        .and()
    // must not compile:
    //.and()
    .build();

User jane = userBuilder // may be injected thorugh some means
    .withName("Jane Doe")
    .withGroup()
        .name("default")
        // must not compile:
        // .build()
        .and()
    .withEmail("jane@doe.com")
    // must not compile:
    // .and()
    .build()
```

**My solution**

follows the following concept:

- One `UserBuilder` for "root"-consturction having a `User build()`-method,
- One `UserBuilderNested`, if a `User` is constructed within the construction of another object, thus providing an `and()`-method, which internally calls some callback-function, passing the constructed user to the enclosing builder
- both versions for the `Group`-object.

To avoid [WET-programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#DRY_vs_WET_solutions), I created two interfaces `UserBuilderCore` and `GroupBuilderCore`, containing only the `with...(...)` methods for the respective builder. `UserBuilder` and `UserBuilderNested` implement `UserBuilderCore`; `GroupBuilder` and `GroupBuilderNested` implement `GroupBuilderCore`. The code for `User` and its builders is shown at the end of the question, the code for `Group` and its builders is analogue. The whole code can be found on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/turing85/builderfun/src/master/).

**Pros**

- The interfaces are fully functional and type-safe.

**Cons**

- For every relation in a class (e.g., lets assume each `User` gets an additional `Set<Post> posts` of written posts), one additional generic parameter has to be introduced.
- As of now, `UserImpl` and `GroupImpl` are tightly coupled. I have not yet found a possibility to modify the generic parameters in such a way that I could e.g. inject some `UserBuilderNested` in `GroupImplBuilder`.
- Furhtermore, adding a new `User`-implementation requires the correct generic wiring, as shown in the example implementation.

**Request**

I am looking for ways to improve the code in the following way:

- Avoid adding additional generic parameters for new relationships (if possible).
- Simplify the current design to allow easier extensability.
- Decouple the `UserBuilder`- and `GroupBuilder`-implementations.
- Any other remarks are of course welcome, but I know that the question is already pretty comprehensive. The points above are my main concern.

**Remarks on the provided code**

The code is only a mockup, with no validation or referencial integrity measurements (e.g., when constructing a `Group` within a `User`, the `User` is not added to the constructed `Group`). This is on purpose.

**Source code**

`User.java`:

```
package com.turing.builder;

import java.util.Set;

public interface User {
  String getName();
  String getEmail();
  Set<Group> getGroups();
  void addGroup(Group group);
}

// UserBuilderCore.java
package com.turing.builder;

public interface UserBuilderCore< // @formatter:off
        S extends UserBuilderCore<S, C>,
        C extends GroupBuilderNested<C, ?, S>> { // @formatter:on
  S withName(String name);
  S withEmail(String email);
  S withGroup(Group group);
  C withGroup();
}
```

`UserBuilder.java`:

```
package com.turing.builder;

public interface UserBuilder< // @formatter:off
        S extends UserBuilder<S, C>,
        C extends GroupBuilderNested<C, ?, S>> // @formatter:on
    extends UserBuilderCore<S, C> {
  User build();
}
```

`UserBuilderNested.java`:

```
package com.turing.builder;

public interface UserBuilderNested< // @formatter:off
        S extends UserBuilderNested<S, C, P>,
        C extends GroupBuilderNested<C, ?, S>,
        P extends GroupBuilderCore<P, ?>> // @formatter:on
    extends UserBuilderCore<S, C> {
  P and();
}
```

`UserImpl.java`:

```
package com.turing.builder.impl;

import com.turing.builder.Group;
import com.turing.builder.User;
import com.turing.builder.UserBuilder;
import com.turing.builder.UserBuilderCore;
import com.turing.builder.UserBuilderNested;
import com.turing.builder.impl.GroupImpl.GroupImplBuilderCore;
import com.turing.builder.impl.GroupImpl.GroupImplBuilderNested;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class UserImpl implements User {
  private String name;
  private String email;
  private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<>();

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  private void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  private void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }

  @Override
  public Set<Group> getGroups() {
    return groups;
  }

  private void setGroups(Set<Group> groups) {
    this.groups = groups;
  }

  @Override
  public void addGroup(Group group) {
    this.groups.add(group);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.format("User %s=%s",
        getName(),
        getGroups().stream()
            .map(Group::getName)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
  }

  protected abstract static class UserImplBuilderCore< // @formatter:off
          S extends UserImplBuilderCore<S>>
      implements UserBuilderCore<
          /* S = */ S,
          /* C = */ GroupImplBuilderNested<S>> { // @formatter:on
    private UserImpl managed = new UserImpl();

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public S withName(String name) {
      managed.setName(name);
      return ((S) this);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public S withEmail(String email) {
      managed.setEmail(email);
      return ((S) this);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public S withGroup(Group group) {
      managed.addGroup(group);
      return ((S) this);
    }

    @Override
    public GroupImplBuilderNested<S> withGroup() {
      return new GroupImplBuilderNested<>(this::withGroup);
    }

    protected User construct() {
      User constructed = this.managed;
      this.managed = new UserImpl();
      return constructed;
    }
  }

  public static class UserImplBuilder extends UserImplBuilderCore<UserImplBuilder>
      implements UserBuilder< // @formatter:off
          /* S = */ UserImplBuilder,
          /* C = */ GroupImplBuilderNested<UserImplBuilder>> { // @formatter:on
    public User build() {
      return construct();
    }
  }

  public static class UserImplBuilderNested<T extends GroupImplBuilderCore<T>>
      extends UserImplBuilderCore<UserImplBuilderNested<T>>
      implements UserBuilderNested< // @formatter:off
          /* S = */ UserImplBuilderNested<T>,
          /* C = */ GroupImplBuilderNested<UserImplBuilderNested<T>>,
          /* P = */ T> { // @formatter:on
    private final Function<User, T> callback;

    public UserImplBuilderNested(Function<User, T> callback) {
      this.callback = callback;
    }

    public T and() {
      return callback.apply(construct());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop nested builders and use separate builders for each type of object to be created (`GroupBuilder`, `UserBuilder`, `WhateverBuilder`).

Then you may use the builders like so:

```
Group root = GroupBuilder
    .withName("root")
    .withUser(UserBuilder.
        .withName("John Doe")
        .withEmail("john@doe.com")
        // ...
        .build())
    .withUser(UserBuilder.
        .withName("Jane Doe")
        .withEmail("jane@doe.com")
        .build())
    .build();
```

This is easier to implement and probably easier to understand for users.

Comment: I am aware of this solution and it is already implemented in my solution.